# How to fill only the second column of a HTML table with data from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the page I currently have:
[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auap4.png)

I am quite the beginner so bear with me!
I want to replace the column that says 'test' with data from a database through javascript. The first column can stay hardcoded in HTML, but the second column needs to be javascript. How would I go about this? Would the entire table have to be made in javascript or is there another way to fix this?

Current HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bedrijf</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="./bedrijfslijst.html">
        <button type="button" class="btnGedetailleerd">Terug</button>
    </a>
    <a href="./index.html">
        <button type="button" class="btnGedetailleerd">Home</button>
    </a>
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="containerDetails">
        <table id="bedrijfDetails">
            <tr>
                <td>Naam</td>
                <td>test</td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sector</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ondernemingsnummer</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Adres</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Aantal werknemers</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Omzet</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Balanstotaal</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Framework</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>B2B/B2C</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Duurzaamheidsrapportering - percentage </td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Duurzaamheidsrapportering - score</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
</body>
<script src="./js/gedetailleerd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

and js code:

```js
function weergaveBedrijf(gekozenBedrijf) {

    let title = document.getElementById("title");
    let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    let text = document.createTextNode(`Gedetailleerd overzicht van "${gekozenBedrijf}"`);
  
    h1.append(text);
    title.append(h1);

};

let gekozenBedrijf = localStorage.getItem("zoekterm");

weergaveBedrijf(gekozenBedrijf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop through rows, try this one:

```
  const stringToFillSecondColumn = 'foo'
  const lastColumn = document.querySelectorAll('#bedrijfDetails tr td:last-child')
  for (const cell of lastColumn) {
    cell.innerHTML = stringToFillSecondColumn
  }
```